# Ensure total order in table via constraint

Tags: postgresql

Suppose I have a table

```
create table log (id serial, logged_at timestamp, event_type integer)
```

Can I efficiently (without making every row writable only once or by some special user) ensure that
`∄ (r1, r2) ∈ log X log (r1.id > r2.id ∧ r2.logged_at > r1.logged_at)`

So events in log partially ordered by time and we can always have total order via monotonically increasing sequence.

Comment: By constraint, do you mean a declarative constraint or would you be ok with a trigger validating modifications to the table?

Comment: Why do you need that? Why isn't the ordering imposed by the timestamp enough?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name timestamp do not impose total order. Do I need to elaborate on that more?

Comment: @Lennart I would consider using trigger as 'inefficient', but If you think it can be O(1) operation I would like to hear about that.

Comment: Anything concerning more than the current row can hardly be O(1), declarative or not. A primary key constraint is normally O(log(n)) for example

Comment: @Lennart Yes, of course. It's more accurate to say I would agree to anything that's not O(n) and worse.

Comment: My question was: why do you think you **need** it? The `id` is presumably the primary key and relying on an ordering of the primary key is usually a bad idea to begin with. The only job of a PK is to be unique. 42 is just as good a primary key value as -468 or 346737. So why is an ordering with a resolution of one microsecond not enough? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve by additionally relying on the order of a unique value?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't want to delve into exact problem, but without total ordering you can't reason about causality. Say we have records of who's fired the bullet at whom at specific times. Without knowing the order we can't reason about who was defending himself and who was attacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some assumptions, it is not allowed to manipulate the log, so I'll just handle the insert. id in itself is monotonically increasing, so what need to check is whether there exists a ts bigger than the current ts:

```
create or replace function validate_total_order() 
returns trigger as $$                                                                              
begin 
    if exists ( select 1 from log where logged_at > NEW.logged_at ) then 
        raise exception 'some message...'; 
    end if; 
    return new; 
end; 
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger validate_total_order 
before insert on log 
for each row 
    execute procedure validate_total_order();
```

with an index on logged_at, it should be reasonable fast.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an occurrence of: *can the database enforce constraints across rows?*
(I assume that the `X` sign in the formula means "*such that*")

As a general rule, the answer is no, because when a row is being modified by a transaction, the state of the other rows is always uncertain due to possible modifications by not-yet-committed concurrent transactions.

An application may handle this correctly by implementing an adequate locking strategy preventing concurrent writes, or checking the constraint at the serializable isolation level, but that does not prevent a random session to just issue an UPDATE in the table without these safety measures, that would potentially result in quietly violating the constraint.

There are few kinds of [table-level constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html) that the SQL engine knows how to enforce, like unique constraints and exclusion constraints, but your formula doesn't look like an expression that could be used by such constraints.

Comment: Is it possible that `X` be a cartesian product?

Comment: Like `∄ (r1, r2) ∈ log X log` meaning _there is no such (r1, r2) pair belonging to the cartesian product of log and log_.

Comment: That's exactly the case. I even used unicode symbol for product I believe. Not an `X` letter.